# Actionbar not work in extends ListActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

hi i tried searching how use actionbar in extends ListActivity.

please help me.

my activity code :

```
public class  extends ListActivity{

        private String[] items;
        private database db;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sharedlist);

            db=new database(this);
            db.open();

            items=new String[db.count("content")];

            setListAdapter(new AAD());

            db.close();

        }
        class AAD extends ArrayAdapter{

            public AAD() {
                super(s.this,R.layout.row,items);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
                LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
                View row=in.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
                TextView username=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_username);
                TextView maintext=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_maintext);
                db.open();
                username.setText(db.Display_shared(position, 1).toString());
                maintext.setText(db.Display_shared(position, 2).toString());
                db.close();
                return (row);


            }




        }


    }
```

and my listview code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if you have sample code please give me.

Comment: Use getActionBar(); in your activtiy.

Comment: How do you do? Please give examples

Comment: Actionbar actionbar = getActionBar(); actionbar.show();

Comment: Which api level you are using

Comment: Use actionabaractivtiy instead of listactivtiy.

Comment: if change to actionabaractivtiy.  setListAdapter(new AAD());  not work and show erorr

Comment: for api 8 you have to use actionabaractivtiy otherwise set your api above 11.

Comment: check your theme also in manifest.